# A Mock'ed service call returning Null instead of false - why?

Tags: unit-testing, moq, c#-9.0

The mocked service is:

```
public async Task<bool> AddAndSaveEventAsync(DomainEvent evt);
```

It is being called from:

```
commandResult = await JSEventService.AddAndSaveEventAsync(new JobSeekerCreatedDomainEvent(jobSeeker));
```

The code in my UnitTest is:

```
var domainEvent = new JobSeekerCreatedDomainEvent(js);

JSDomainEventService.Setup(eventService => eventService.AddAndSaveEventAsync(domainEvent))
                    .Returns(Task.FromResult(true));
```

The domain event is valid when I debug.  It does step into the CommandHandler where the code that calls the JSEventService is called from.

I dont know why the call to AddAndSaveEventAsync() is returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're passing in an actual object in to the mocking call.

You should be using either `It.Is<>` or `It.IsAny<>` so that the matcher matches against the shape of the object and not an actual reference.

Comment: Are you referring to the domainEvent?

Comment: That is wierd because right above I have:             'code' var js = new JobSeeker());

            JSRepository.Setup(jsRepo => jsRepo.Add(js));                                         
And it works

Comment: Could it be a false positive?

Comment: It may work for other reasons; jsRepo.Add may not be overridable, JobSeeker may be a struct etc. This answer is correct in that when dealing with a reference you need to use the Moq matchers